# jQuery range slider event trigger

Tags: jquery, slider, range

there`s a problem using the jQuery Range Slider plugin. I want to trigger an event every time the slider changed.

I don`t know on which elemt i can trigger events. For exmaple i wana have an alert message ro see if it works.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 7):

To get the slider value once the user has stopped moving the knob use `change` otherwise use `input` to receive updates as the knob is moved.

```
// Logs the value when the user has released the slider
$('.my-slider').on('change', valueUpdated);

// Logs the value while the user is moving the slider
$('.my-slider').on('input', valueUpdated);

function valueUpdated (e) {
    var val = $(e.element).val();
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 possible events you can use. Look under events in the docs ==> http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

You can use the

1. **[start](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-start)**
2. **[slide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-slide)**
3. **[change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change)**
4. **[stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop)**

events.

If you want to do a function everytime the slider is changed try `change`.

Let's say your slide is an element with id of `slider`:

```
$(function() {    // <== doc ready

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
       change: function(event, ui) {
           // Do your stuff in here.

           // You can trigger an event on anything you want:
           $(selector).trigger(theEvent);

           // Or you can do whatever else/
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: That's not rangeslider, that's jquery UI

Comment: Wrong library I think.