# JQuery range events not firing.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update a value when a user changes the value on the JQuery range control. I have tried to follow the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983155/jquery-range-slider-event-trigger), however it does not work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ready1'); //This fires when the page loads. 

        // Logs the value while the user is moving the slider
        $('.price-min').on('input', getValue);

        function getValue(e) { //This never fires 
            var val = $(e.element).val();
            alert(val); 
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="200" min="0" max="1000">
    <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="800" min="0" max="1000">
</div>
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the the function be declared before you try to use it

Comment: You are not selecting any element in your attempt to bind the event handler. id/name != class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things with your code.

1. You are selecting an element by it's class (`$('.price-min')`), but your ranges have an ID (`$('#price-min)'`).
2. Listen to `change` event.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function getValue(e) { // now this fires on range change event 
            var val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val); 
        }
        // Logs the value while the user is moving the slider
        $('#price-min').on('change', getValue);


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <input type="range" name="price-min" id="price-min" value="200" min="0" max="1000">
    <input type="range" name="price-max" id="price-max" value="800" min="0" max="1000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the class selector:

```
.price-min
```

Instead of the id selector:

```
#price-min
```

You also need to get *this* instead of *e.element*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('ready1'); //This fires when the page loads. 

  // Logs the value while the user is moving the slider
  $('#price-min').on('input', getValue);

  function getValue(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val); 
  }
});
```